# How Can I Configure Storybook to Use React-App-Rewired?

Tags: reactjs, ffmpeg, storybook, react-app-rewired, sharedarraybuffer

I'm working on a project that implements react-app-rewired to send headers to the server in order to bypass `ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined` (I'm getting this error from using the `@ffmpeg/ffmpeg` library).

```js
// config-overrides.js
const {
  override,
  // disableEsLint,
  // addBabelPlugins,
  // overrideDevServer
} = require('customize-cra')

module.exports = {
  devServer(configFunction) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line func-names
    return function (proxy, allowedHost) {
      const config = configFunction(proxy, allowedHost)

      // Set loose allow origin header to prevent CORS issues
      config.headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy': 'same-origin',
        'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy': 'require-corp',
        'Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy': 'cross-origin'
      }

      return config
    }
  }
}
```

```json
// package.json
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-app-rewired start",
  "build": "react-app-rewired build",
  "test": "react-app-rewired test  --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!siriwave)/\"",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
  "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
}
```

Though this works when I run `npm start`, meaning the headers get sent to the server, it doesn't work when I run `npm run storybook`, and I still get the `SharedArrayBuffer is not defined` error. I'm assuming it's because `npm run storybook` still uses `react-scripts` as opposed to `react-app-rewired` under the hood, but I'm not sure where I can change the configurations for this. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? If you did, can you elaborate on how you did it? I am going through same error right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom webpack configuration in storybook/main.js like so:
https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/builders/webpack

So you can use the same webpack modification as you did with react-app-rewired